# PYTHON TKINTER set focus to next row instead of next widget

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, focus, frame

I have frames in a grid with widgets in them. These frames get destroyed and new ones are created. I want to move between these with keyboard.
The Problem: every time there is a new frame it gets treated by focus next as the last one.
The Question: how to focus by row instead.

```
    def create_a_line(i):
        p=1 #sometimes there are more widgets in a row, but here just take 1
        bframe = Frame(root)
        bframe.grid(row=i, column=0)
        m = Button(bframe, text=h[i], , takefocus = 1)
        m.bind('<Right>', lambda event, i=i: focus_next(i, p))
        m.bind('<Double-1>', lambda event, i=i: double_click_text(i)) 
        m.grid(row=0, column=p)
        
    def double_click_text(i)
        for widget in root.grid_slaves(row=i):
           widget.destroy()
        #change h[i] i.e. text of the button to something else
        create_a_line(i) #with new text but same row
    
    def focus_next(i, p):  #this is what im struggling with
          event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus() #this is how it is right now
#this is how i would like it to be, but no idea how:
#        if in row=i other widgets with column >p: sometimes there will be more than one widget in a row
#          event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
#        else:
#          set_focus(first widget in grid row=i+1)
    
    for i in range(0, 5) #the end number is based on number of lines f.e. 5
        create_a_line(i)
```

Comment: I think you can just have a list and insert in the list in the same index as it has row and then you can simply use an index on that list to focus on a row

Comment: Please create a complete [mcve]. The code you posted doesn't delete or add new frames.

Comment: @Matiiss this would be a great solution, but I still dont know how to set focus by index. For example i have a list ["1,0","1,3","2,0","2,3"] with ["row,column"] of all widgets. Now how to focus for example widget in "2,0". Or would i have to make ["row, widget_name"] list?

Comment: all you need is add the widget to the list in the index that has the same value as its supposed row. In the list you would have the Frame objects and their index in the list would be row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a better solution this is how I solved it based on comments:

```
labellsall=[]
h = [] 
def ad_to_labelsall(i,  p , z):
    ag = ["#"+str(i)+"i@", p, z]  #made i more complicated so I dont find random numbers
    labelsall.append(ag)

def del_from_labelsall(i):
    agi = ("#"+str(i)+"i@")
    ngip = [e for e, s in enumerate(labelsall) if agi in s]
    for index in sorted(ngip, reverse=True):
       del labelsall[index]

def create_a_line(i):
    p=1 
    bframe = Frame(root)
    bframe.grid(row=i, column=0)
    m = Button(bframe, text=h[i], , takefocus = 1)
    m.bind('<Right>', lambda event, i=i: focus_next(event, i))
    m.bind('<Double-1>', lambda event, i=i: double_click_text(i)) 
    m.grid(row=0, column=p)
    ad_to_labelsall(i,  p , z=m)

def double_click_text(i)
    del_from_labelsall(i)
    for widget in root.grid_slaves(row=i):
       widget.destroy()
    #some other code change h[i] i.e. text of the button to something else
    create_a_line(i) #with new text but same row

def focus_next(event, i):
    grid_info = event.widget.grid_info()
    p = grid_info["column"]
    agi = ("#"+str(i)+"i@") 
    ngip = [e for e, s in enumerate(labelsall) if agi in s]
    for index in sorted(ngip):
       the_row = labelsall[index]
       if int(the_row[1]) > p:   #check if other widget is in the row before jumping to next row
          the_row[2].focus_set() #if other widget found focus it
          return("break")
       else:
          pass
    i_next = i+1
    try:
      agi_next = ("#"+str(i_next)+"i@")
      ngip_next = [e for e, s in enumerate(labelsall) if agi_next in s]
      labelsall[ngip_next[0]][2].focus_set()
    except:
      agi_next = ("#"+str(i_next+1)+"i@") #sometimes there are rows with no widgets, so just try the next one
      ngip_next = [e for e, s in enumerate(labelsall) if agi_next in s]
      labelsall[ngip_next[0]][2].focus_set()
   return("break")
```